# Cauchy distribution and Fisher information

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, fisher-information

Let $X$ has a Cauchy distribution with p.d.f. 
$$
f(x,\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi\left\{ 1+\left(x-\theta\right)^{2}\right\} }
$$
, $-\infty<x<\infty$, $-\infty<\theta<\infty$.

The characteristic function of this distribution is 
$$
\phi\left(t\right)=e^{i\theta t-|t|}.
$$

> Question is : What is the Fisher information contained in $\bar{X}$?

I know that $\phi_{\bar{X}}\left(t\right)=\phi(t)$. It is Qualification exam problem,
but what does this question want me to do?

Comment: What does Fisher Information tell you about? Information about a parameter? Information about something else?

Comment: @wolfies Actually I don't get any point in the question. I guess the question need us to say 'Because the characteristic function is same, the Fisher information contained in $\bar{X}$ is same with the one of $X$. How do you think about my opinion?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158292/cramer-rao-lower-bound-in-cauchy-distribution/